# Meteor: How to do a case insensitive collection.findOne()?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm implementing a way for users to change their username in a Meteor app I am writing. Before accepting changes, I want to check if the username already exists. Usernames can contain upper and lowercase, but they must be unique names regardless of case. For example, `bob` and `Bob` cannot exist together.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to do a `collection.findOne()` that is case insensitive. For example, say I have a collection called Profiles, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
newName = "bob";

//Assume "Bob" exists as a username in the Profiles collection;

var isAlreadyRegistered = Profiles.findOne({"username": newName});

if (isAlreadyRegistered == null) {
  saveUsername();
};
```

Answer (score 23):

Your can use [regular expression.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

```
var isAlreadyRegistered = Profiles.findOne({"username": /^newName$/i });
```

Or you can query like this also :

```
 var isAlreadyRegistered = Profiles.findOne({ "username" : {
                     $regex : new RegExp(newName, "i") } }
               );
```

Comment: Great answer, but I do wonder why your first example doesn't work for me while the second one does.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways and your mileage may vary on the best approach for you, but both are fairly horrible actually since MongoDB does case "sensitive" matching:

First approach is to use [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

```js
Profiles.findOne({ "username": { 
    "$regex": "^" + newName + "\\b", "$options": "i"
}})
```

That matches the word and only the exact word from the beginning of the string in a case insensitive way. The problem here is that you are scanning an index.

The second approach is to project using aggregate:

```js
db.collection("profiles").aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "username": 1,
        "lower": { "$toLower": "$username" }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "username": newName
    }}
])
```

And you do that where of course `newName` has already been converted to lowercase.

The problem here is that will **`$project`** over everything in the pipeline. But can be useful if you can possibly **`$match`** first.

Of course I think that **`aggregate`** is only available on the server side and not through Minimongo, so there is that to consider.

Comment: I believe I did say that and also stated that can use this on the server inside your own method.

Comment: @AndrewMao for the benefit of all readers and yourself, that statement is false. All framework implementations at some point use and allow access to the underlying driver and its methods, so by grabbing the native collection object you should always be able to get this method, and also as most frameworks do provide at least an interface to "runCommand" in some form it can also be done this way. All MongoDB methods in drivers are actually implemented in this way. So regardless of the calling syntax you should not say that it id not available.

Answer (score 2):

As a solution to your underlying use-case, I suggest using two fields to store the username rather than one.

The built-in username field should store the lowercase version of the username.  The other, extra field stores the original case-sensitive version.

Searches would be conducted against the 'username' field with the search criteria lowercased as well before use.

Comment: Under the general premise of what **should** be done. You are very correct in that there needs to be a field that actually has the lowercase value within the document and indexed. But the other options merely exist as showing that there actually **are** ways to do this, and even "on the fly" which often get overlooked.

Comment: Yep, its one of those interesting cases where the question is asking something specific to which there are good answers but the actual best-practice to solve the underlying problem wasn't actually asked.